# asp.net additional data to the right side of the page

Tags: asp.net

This has to be really simple, but I am really new to all this. I have an asp .Net page that looks like this:

[image]

This is just a result of a `<table>` tag in the markup. Just simple labels and textboxes on new rows.

I am trying to add a few details to this. I want my page to look like this:

[image]

Just add a section to the right side of the page and maybe draw a vertical line in between the two sections to separate them.

I tried inserting a few `<td>`'s in the same row as where `Weight Ticket` is and then add a `<td>` for `Load #:` but it just throws it right next to each other. Do I just insert a new table? If I do, how do I align it to the right?

I am so lost, I cannot even think of what to Google to see how I can do this. I know this has to be a BASIC asp.NET question, but I'd really appreciate some help. Even as little as "Google this:" would help.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are already using tables in your designs, and I do not want to suggest something out of ordinary which will break your page design. Create a bigger table of one row with 2 td. One of width 60%, another 40%. Place your existing table HTML in first td. Design the next one in another one.

Comment: Trying it out now. Will get back to you on how it works out

Comment: That works! Thank you :) If you want to post it as an answer, I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using tables in your designs, and I do not want to suggest something out of ordinary which will break your page design. Create a bigger table of one row with 2 td. One of width 60%, another 40%. Place your existing table HTML in first td. Design the next one in another one.